# where are indexing configuration in OpenGrok docker image?

Tags: docker, svn, indexing, opengrok

I am trying to setup an OpenGrok instance from a docker image. By default svn indexer inside the image is checking for new repositories in 10 minutes.
I need to change this configuration. From where exactly I can change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I posted this I found the related files inside docker container at `/scripts`.

Here `REINDEX` variable is defined in `start.sh` script.